# Why delegate dictionary pattern with async lambda never returns while calling IAuthenticated.Subscriptions.ListAsync?

Tags: .net, azure, async-await, delegates

I am calling async lambda which is stored in dictionary. This async lambda points to awaitable method which uses Azure subscriptions.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ISubscription>> GetAllSubscriptions()
{
   List<ISubscription> subscriptions = new List<ISubscription>();
   //return await azureAuthenticated.Subscriptions.ListAsync();
   foreach (var subscription in await azureAuthenticated.Subscriptions.ListAsync())
   {
       subscriptions.Add(subscription);
   }
        
   return subscriptions;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<AzureSubscription>> GetAllSubscriptions()
{
    return (await connectionProvider.GetAllSubscriptions()).ToList()
                .Select(s => new AzureSubscription { SubscriptionId = s.SubscriptionId, 
    DisplayName = s.DisplayName, State = s.State });
}
```

The dictionary is :

```
private IDictionary<string, Func<Task<List<string>>>> _GetDropDownControlDynamicData;
```

while dictionary initialization is :

```
    _GetDropDownControlDynamicData = new Dictionary<string, Func<Task<List<string>>>>()
    {    
        ["Subscription"] = async () => (await _azureService.GetAllSubscriptions()).Select(pr => pr.DisplayName).ToList(),
        ["OsDiskTypes"] = async () => (await _azureService.GetOsDiskTypes()).Select(pr => pr.DisplayName).ToList()
    }
```

Here, when the caller invokes the lambda using following line.

**`var subscriptions = _GetDropDownControlDynamicData[parameter.Name]().Result.ToList()`** this call never returns. I dont' know why..?

Am I not using the lambda rightly? or I should not write delegate dictionary pattern at all for issuing these types of calls.

Can any body help here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> when the caller invokes the lambda using [.Result], this call never returns. I dont' know why..?

[Blocking on asynchronous code can cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) if there is a single-threaded context present (e.g., ASP.NET pre-Core).

Ideally, the solution would be to use `await` instead of `Result`:

```
var subscriptions = (await _GetDropDownControlDynamicData[parameter.Name]()).ToList();
```

If that isn't possible for some reason, then there are [some hacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) that may help.